# Enforce right method overload to be called

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, overloading

I have two methods with the following signatures:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value) { ... }

public void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> value) { ... }
```

I'm trying to call the second one like this:

```
DoSomething(new[] { "Pizza", "Chicken", "Cheese" });
```

It still jumps into the first one.
How can I enforce that it will enter the second method instead? For example by using a where clause for the generic parameter?

**Edit:**

To be more precise: Why does it not work, even if I am more specific and change the overloads to something like this, which will result in an compile error when trying to call the method like shown above:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value) where T : IComparable { ... }

public void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> value) where T : IComparable { ... }
```

Comment: Rename the second one to `DoSomethingToACollection`

Comment: I already thought about this, but I still would like to keep the names same. I also don't quite understand, why it compiles then.

Comment: In life we cannot always have everything we want.  Your `T value` parameter will capture everything, since everything is a `T`.  You dont want two different methods to have the same name, one explicitly handles an `IEnumerable`, the other explicitly handles a `T` save yourself headache and just change the names.

Comment: @maccettura: But the array is also an `IEnumerable<T>` so the question isn't why does the first one match but how, given both of them match, it chooses which one is called.

Comment: You can specify the generic type explicitly `DoSomething<string>` when calling the method.

Comment: Can you change the first overload to accept `object` instead of being generic?

Comment: @NetMage This honestly seems to work for me in the `string` scenario. Maybe you could detail this in an answer and clarify if it will work with other structs and reference types.

Comment: I really wouldn't change it to `object`, that's even worse. Avoid using `object` except when you have no other choice (e.g. calling some OS functions or other libraries that require `object` or types that cannot convert to C# types).

Comment: @RacilHilan While we don't have the body of `DoSomething`, we do know it returns `void`, so any use of `object` extends just inside the body. I am not sure I can think of a case where using `object` instead of the generic type will be a disadvantage?

Comment: @NetMage You have several features for generics, but nearly nothing for `object`. It's hard to compare them in a comment, but here are two: you can explicitly specify the type of `T` when you call the function, you cannot do that with `object`. You can use constrains for `T`, not for `object`. Just take the .Net framework as an example, how often `object` is used vs generics, even though generics are much newer than `object`. If you like, ask it in a question and we will try to answer it for you.

Comment: I'm interested in that answer as well. Please keep me posted.

Comment: @RacilHilan Except I don't see how either of those matter, especially in this case. How is explicitly specifying the type useful as opposed to the compiler inferring the type from the expression passed? This function doesn't use constraints, so not meaningful for this question.

Comment: @NetMage Yes, the OP didn't use them, but those options are available. Use `object` and you'll have none of those options. But again, those are just two points among others. How about casting and boxing for example? Cannot do it in comments.

Comment: I tried something completely different. Final solution to be found here:
https://github.com/gravityctrl/FilterChili/blob/479c9f7d386b85e97a03f4e06ac36ce9a49a69f3/src/FilterChili/Selectors/FilterSelector.cs#L108

Answer (score 7):

You can explicitly cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` reference at first place after initialization and then pass in to the method as parameter like following, so that it resolves to more specific overload which would be `IEnumerable<T>` not `T`:

```
DoSomething(new[] { "Pizza", "Chicken", "Cheese" } as IEnumerable<string>);
```

or this can also be done:

```
IEnumerable<string> foods = new[] { "Pizza", "Chicken", "Cheese" };
DoSomething(foods);
```

The problem is when you do not cast it to `IEnumerable<T>`, it's type at compile time is `String[]`, so it would resolve to the overload which take `T` as input parameter.

So at calling time, your code actually is compile like:

```
DoSomething<String[]>(foods);
```

So it calls the first overload instead of the second one.

Another solution to this is to specify the generic type parameter yourself explicitly instead of compiler to resolve itself like:

```
DoSomething<String>(foods);
```

Refer to the following demo fiddle i just created to explain it:

[Demo Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jyibql)

### Edit:

As some people are suggesting the better would be to change the method name to be obvious enough that one can understand for what kind of types it can process, though the work around that i mention would work.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: While this does work, OP is likely better off changing the method names to avoid confusion later on.

Comment: yes you are right, the method name should be clear for what purpose it is

Comment: Or just `DoSomething<string>(new[] { "Pizza"})`

Comment: yes you are absolutely right @CamiloTerevinto updated the post

Answer (score 5):

When there are multiple applicable overloads of a method there are several different factors that are used to determine which one is "better".  One of those factors is how "close" each of the parameters are to the types in the method signature.  `string[]` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, so it's *valid* in that parameter slot, but `string[]` is *closer* to `string[]` (an exact match is as "close" as it gets) than it is to `IEnumerable<string>`, so the first overload is "closer" than the second.

So if you change the compile time type of your second parameter to exactly `IEnumerable`, then both overloads will be exactly the same on the "closeness" scale.  Since that's the same, it goes on to another "betterness" tiebreaker, which is that non-generic methods are "better" than generic methods, so you end up calling the overload that you want.

As far as how to change the compile time type of that expression to `IEnumerable<string>`, the most convenient way would be `AsEnumerable`:

```
DoSomething(new[] { "Pizza", "Chicken", "Cheese" }.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Or just `DoSomething<string>(new[] { "Pizza"})`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in @Servy's excellent answer, the compiler will choose the best matching type for overloaded methods.

By changing the generic function to use `object` instead, you cause anything that is an `IEnumerable<>` to match that function best.

```
public void DoSomething(object value) { ... }

public void DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> value) { ... }
```

I think it may be theoretically possible that downcasting `value` to `object` could cause a performance issue versus the generic method, but since `DoSomething` doesn't return the `value` or take another parameter of matching type `T`, the use of `object` is restricted to the body of `DoSomething` and will allow all uses that are legal for `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `T` accepts all the types and `string[]` is not an `IEnumerable` directly. It is derived from it.

```
DoSomething(new[] { "Pizza", "Chicken", "Cheese" }.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: "`string[]` is not an `IEnumerable`."  It sure is.  If it wasn't, then your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: `typeof(object[]).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)) == true`

Comment: @Jonathon Chase, of course it is true. Array implements IEnumerable anyway.